# Double click when clicking once pynput

Tags: python, pynput

Trying to do a program that double clicks for you when you click the left mouse button once with pynput. I have the following code, but if I run the code, my mouse glitches out and stops working.

```
from pynput.mouse import Listener, Button, Controller

mouse = Controller()

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    if pressed == True:
        mouse.click(Button.left, 2)
    else:
        pass

with Listener(on_click=on_click) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Also in addition of this, how would the implementation of pressing "F10" enables that 1 click acts like double click and pressing "F10" again would disable it, so 1 click would act like 1 click be possible?

Comment: I can't use `mouse.click(Button.left, 2)`.It will make my mouse don't work.

Comment: Yeah, I think that's the problem. But the function is in pynput's documentation. https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html#controlling-the-mouse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh,I maybe find your problem,
Two probable causes:

1. In your script,when your press the mouse button.It will call function `on_click`.Then it will `mouse.click(Button.left, 2)`.But this code will also call `on_click`.So it will be a endless loop.Finally,you will find your mouse will be not responding.So I think you should use another way to do that.
2. In `pynput` official document,It seems it can be used in macOS(maybe windows couldn't use it.And I also found if I only use `mouse.click(Button.left, 2)` in my PC,my python will be not responding.(It couldn't be stopped).Maybe you should just use `.press` and `.release` directly):
   [image]

> Also in addition of this, how would the implementation of pressing "F10" enables that 1 click acts like double click and pressing "F10" again would disable it.

So this seems a switch,you can use a `global` variable to do that.There is a minimal example of use pynput to do a switch.(This will don't print `Mode is on` if you don't press F10,and it won't print it after you press F10 again).

```
# import win32api,win32con
from pynput.mouse import Controller
from pynput import keyboard
from pynput.keyboard import Key

mouse = Controller()
Mode = False

def on_press(key):
    global Mode
    if key == Key.f10:
        if Mode:
            Mode = False
        else:
            Mode = True

listener = keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press)
listener.start()
while True:
    if Mode:
        print("Mode is on")
```